# Retain formatting on a used value

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

There are two sheets, one containing columns with date ranges ("Test" sheet), the other containing payment amounts with specific dates ("Payment information" sheet).

I wrote code, that goes line by line in the second sheet and checks if the date falls between a date range in the first based on supplier values existing in both sheets.

Where I am stuck:
Payment amounts contain formatting for currencies e.g. €, $ or different. If I use something like the code below - it retains the formatting, however: the same cell in "Test" sheet, might have to have the sum of multiple lines from "Payment information" and copy pasting replaces the values.

```vb
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Payment information").Cells(i, "F").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(last_row, j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

If alternatively I use the code below - the formatting drops off:

```vb
payment_amount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Payment information").Cells(i, "F")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(last_row, j).value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(last_row, j).value + payment_amount
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can do a PasteSpecial xlformats to just copy those.

So going from

```
Range("A1").Copy
Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlFormats
```

On your example:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Payment information").Cells(i, "F").Copy 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(last_row, j).PasteSpecial xlFormats
```

Adding from your comment below, you should use a variable that adds value when it meets conditions.

For example

```
Dim payment as Integer

Select case Range("A2").Value

  Case #1/1/2022# To #12/31/2022#
  payment = payment + Range("A2")
  Case else
  payment = Range("A2").Value
```

So the code goes like this: If it happens to be in 2022, it adds the value to your variable.
If it's not in 2022, it copies the value

You then can paste/show the value in your desired range, like:

```
Range("A2").Value = payment
```

Combining it with an iteration to check dates and it should work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The issue with this is, if there is already a value in the target cell - that value gets replaced using this method. E.g. A1 contains 50eu and I need an additional 50 added on top - the end result will be 50, but not 100.